# Unit testing silverlight classes throws System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Invalid cross-thread access

Tags: c#, silverlight, unit-testing

I'm writing unit tests for my silverlight classes. Everytime I use of instance of a class/control from silverlight, I usually get this exception.

**System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Invalid cross-thread access.**

However, with other types, the silverlight unit test project is okay.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using Microsoft.Silverlight.Testing;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

[TestMethod]
public void SomeTest()
{
    var someTextBox = new TextBox(); // exception is triggered here
    // assume logic
}
```

Comment: Hard to say without code...

Comment: updated with a simple code snippet.

Comment: It is odd to throw an exception for the code you updated. Are you calling any multi-threaded code or asynchronous code part of your test?

Comment: hi Raj, as you can see, its fairly simple. I'm just accessing an ordinary silverlight textbox control. No threading or whatsoever. I haven't even called the actual class I'm going to test yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i've solved it. the issue only is found whenever I use ReSharper for running my silverlight unit tests. But if i use the built in running web app for the silverlight tests, the exception is gone

Answer (score 0):

You probably need [AgUnit](http://agunit.codeplex.com/) plugin for R# to run and debug Silverlight unit tests